# What is the difference between DBPedia and Wikipedia data?

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia, wikipedia-api

May I define (or calculate) the difference between DBPedia and Wikipedia data concerning, for example, Ecuadorian People?

Does DBpedia contain the same Ecuadorian People existing in Wikipedia? If not - what is the difference (e.g. how to extract all Ecuadorian People from Wikipedia)?

I could run SPARQL to calculate the number of Ecuadorian People from DBPedia but do not know how to do it for Wikipedia(what approach?)

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ecuadorians contain all Ecuadorian?

Comment: I think it's better to use Wikidata, than DBPedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia (specifically, mostly its infoboxes) is the *source* for the data in DBpedia. And that applies to each specific piece of information too. For example, take the first person on Wikipedia's *List of Ecuadorians*, Abdón Ubidia ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd%C3%B3n_Ubidia), [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Abd%C3%B3n_Ubidia)):

- DBpedia says that his `birthPlace` is `Quito` and `Ecuador`, because Wikipedia says that he was *Born* in *Quito, Ecuador*
- DBpedia says that his `nationality` is *Ecuadorian*, because Wikipedia says that his *Nationality* is *Ecuador*

But Wikipedia is not completely consistent. If you take the following lists from Wikipedia:

- people that were *Born* somewhere in *Ecuador*
- people whose *Nationality* is *Ecuador*
- people in *List of Ecuadorians*
- people in subcategories of [*Category:Ecuadorian people*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Ecuadorian_people)

then it's very likely you will get 4 different lists of people.

Comment: Also note, DBpedia is an evolving project. Extraction is currently a periodic event, not constant, so DBpedia and Wikipedia content can be out of sync for some time after an update to Wikipedia. Eventually, a properly written query against DBpedia should return a complete merge of the 4 Wikipedia lists -- so one query against DBpedia would effectively deliver a merge of the four Wikipedia lists.

Comment: @svick This issue of consistency that you mentioned also holds for the DBPedia; right?

Comment: @Daniel Like I said, Wikipedia is the source of data for DBPedia, so, yes, the issue does apply to DBPedia too.